# Proof: $\sqrt[n]{n} > \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$

Tags: inequality, induction

How can I prove that $\sqrt[n]{n} > \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus  \{ 1,2 \}$ ?

My approach:

**Step 1:**

$n_0 := 3 \qquad \sqrt[3]{3} > \sqrt[4]{4}$

which is true.

**Step 2:**

$\sqrt[n]{n} > \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$ is true for any $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus  \{ 1,2 \}$

**Step 3:**

$A(n) \rightarrow A(n+1)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>3}$

$\sqrt[n+1]{n+1} > ... > A(n+1)$

And here i don't know how to proceed.

Can someone give me a tip?

Comment: You've tagged this as induction. Do you actually want an induction proof or will any do?

Comment: I've tried with an induction proof but it's not defined that i have to do it with.

Comment: You should explain what you have tried in your question so people have a better sense of how to help you proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt[n]{n} > \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$

$\Leftrightarrow n^{n+1}>(n+1)^n$

> $$\begin{array}{l}\Leftrightarrow n^{n+1}>n^n+n\times n^{n-1}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}n^{n-2}+...+1\\\end{array}$$

From there you shouldn't have much trouble.

Comment: What are the steps to see that 

$\sqrt[n]{n} > \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$

$\Leftrightarrow n^{n+1}>(n+1)^n$

is equivalent?

Comment: Raise both sides to the power of $n(n+1)$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ then $f^{\prime}(x)=f(x)\frac{1-\log x}{x^2}<0$ for $x>e.$

Therefore, $f(x)$ is decreasing function for $x>e.$ Thus $f(n)>f(n+1)$ for $n\geq 3.$

Answer (score 3):

Raising to the power $n(n+1)$ this is equivalent to
$$
n^{n+1}>(n+1)^n
$$
or
$$
n>\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n}
$$
Assuming you know that
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n}<e<3
$$
you're done. See [How is $a_n=(1+1/n)^n$ monotonically increasing and bounded by $3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515317/how-is-a-n-11-nn-monotonically-increasing-and-bounded-by-3)

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt[n]{n} > \sqrt[n+1]{n+1} \iff n^{n+1} > (n+1)^n \iff n > \left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^n$

Now $ 2 \le \left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^n < 3$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** $f(x)=\frac{\log x}{x}$ is a decreasing function over $(e,+\infty)$, since over such set:
$$ f'(x) = \frac{1-\log x}{x^2} < 0.$$
**Step 2.** Our inequality is equivalent to:
$$ \forall n\geq 3,\quad f(n+1)<f(n).$$

Comment: What is $g$ here? - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: typo. Now fixed, thanks.