# How to Find the convergence of this sequence

Tags: calculus

how to find if this sequence converges or diverges. Please help I am having hard time to solve this.

(1+(1/n))^n

Comment: As an aside, it is well known that one of the many definitions or properties of the number $e$ is that $e=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Show that the sequence is *increasing* ($a_n < a_{n+1}$) and *bounded above* (e.g. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : a_n < 3$).

---

For the increasing part, this question gives multiply approaches:

[I have to show $(1+\frac1n)^n$ is monotonically increasing sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/i-have-to-show-1-frac1nn-is-monotonically-increasing-sequence)

See also:

[How is $a_n=(1+1/n)^n$ monotonically increasing and bounded by $3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515317/how-is-a-n-11-nn-monotonically-increasing-and-bounded-by-3)

(I'll flag this as a duplicate to the question above).

Comment: what is the specific technique for that method?

Comment: @UtsavBhattarai I added a few links.