# Does the error always decrease as n increases?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Considering the program below that calculates the mathematical constant,*e* from the definition,
$$e = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n. $$

It computes $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ for $n=10^k$, $k=1,2,..20$.

Program:
Program EApprox
implicit none

```
integer :: n, k
real :: f, abs_error

do k = 1, 20
    n = 10**(k)
    f = (1.0 + 1.0/real(n))**(n)
    abs_error = abs((exp(1.0)) - ((1.0 + 1.0/real(n))**n))
    write(*,*) k, n, f, &
                             abs_error

end do
```

End Program EApprox

Results:
[image: Results Description]

Does the error always decrease as n increases?

Here are some points that I would like further clarifications on:

1. what you see there in terms of the behavior of the error as $n$
   increases.
2. For the first few results, when $n$ increases by a factor of $10 $ what happens to the error? By what rate does it decrease?
3. And then we reach a point, where the error starts to grow. What do you think might be causing that error growth?  And as $n$ continues to decrease by a factor of 10, what is the rate of increase of the error?
4. Here, is it possible to identify that the truncation error behaved
   like $O(h)$. and that the roundoff error behaved like $O(1/h)$? If yes,
   how so?

Comment: $(1+1/n)^n$ *increases* with $n$ (see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/515317/42969), which means that the error term decreases. The problem with your program is that computers have only a limited  floating point precision: If $n$ is large then $1.0 + 1.0/n$ is rounded to $1.0$.

Comment: A reading is [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1187415) on Stack Overflow, and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: (It should have been: “A good reading is ...”)