# I would like to prove that $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function, binomial-theorem

I would like to prove that

$$e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}.$$

Among the several attempts I've performed to prove the previous, I report the one I judge the most promising one, where I've made use of the Newton's binomial theorem:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n 
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n} = \\
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}n^{n-k}1^k}{n^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{n^{k} \cdot (n-k)!k!} = \ldots
$$

Anyway, I'm stuck.

Any hints?

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for this link. Anyway, I've already read it, but the (most voted and accepted) answer is somehow confusing for me.

Comment: Try to adapt my answer here to help answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4452536/29156 But basically this is the prooff from Rudin's PMA.